# How to send a size_t variable with a TCP socket in C?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm working on something that sends data to a TCP server, but first it is supposed to send the size of the data in 8 bytes.

That is, the server will read the first 8 bytes sent to it and cast them back into a size_t variable.  My problem is, when there is a file size that doesn't use any of the top bits (i.e. 83 = 0000000S <- char's, not hex), it only sends the non-zero bytes.

This is how I do it:

```
void send_file_to_server(char *filename){

    struct stat buf;
    if (stat(filename, &buf)==-1){ exit(1); }
    size_t file_size = buf.st_size;

    char *filesize_string = calloc(1, 8);
    filesize_string = (char*)&file_size;

    //this function actually writes to the server
    write_to_server((char*) filesize_string);


   // will be code later on that sends the actual file using write_to_server()

}
```

The char* passed into my write_to_server() function has some weird behavior: it only recognizes it as a string of size 6, and it gets distorted from before it was passed in. Any advice on how to make this work is appreciated.

Note: I do not have to worry about endianness (htonl, etc.) or a differing size of size_t since this is for a project that will only ever be run on a specific VM.

Edits:

here is the other function:

```
void write_to_server(char *message){
    ssize_t bytes_sent = 0;
    ssize_t message_size = strlen(message);

    while ( bytes_sent < message_size ){
        ssize_t ret = write(server_socket, message+bytes_sent, message_size-bytes_sent);
        if (ret==0){
            print_connection_closed(); 
            exit(1);
        }
        if (ret==-1 && (errno!=EINTR || errno!=EAGAIN)){
            printf("write failed: sent %zd bytes out of %zd\n", bytes_sent, message_size);
            exit(1);
        }
        if (ret!=-1){ bytes_sent+=ret; }
    }   
}
```

Comment: *My problem is, when there is a file size that doesn't use any of the top bits* - so this is a wrong logic. Use the correct one which is sending all of the data. Zeroes *are* meaningful..

Comment: What is the `calloc` call for? All it seems to do is leak memory.

Comment: You are passing the address of the `filesize_string` variable to the `write_to_server` function. I suspect that you really wanted to pass the address of the `file_size` variable, or the value of the `filesize_string` variable.

Comment: and you should make good use of `sizeof(size_t)` rather than hardcoding it to 8

Comment: @Ian Abbott It is to get memory that is already set to 0. So the upper bytes of the string are already 0. Yes I guess I did not show it being free'd.

Comment: @Ian Abbott is correct.  What does write_to_server() Do?  Can you show that?

Comment: @EugeneSh. That is the question I am asking... what I was trying to say is when there is a size that isn't big enough to have the upper bytes flipped, it doesn't send the upper bytes. I know there zeroes are meaningful, my problem is I am having trouble sending them.

Comment: "*I do not have to worry about endianness*" <- that's a bald statement, but then just sending the `size_t` with `send()` or `write()` and a size parameter of 8 should do (assuming you also **know** `size_t` has 8 bytes, otherwise convert to `uint64_t` first)

Comment: @IanAbbott oh yes you are right. Before I was sending the address of the size_t so it would cast as a char, but I definitely shouldn't do that for filesize_string. I'll see if fixing that works. Thank you

Comment: `size_t` isn't 8 bytes, it's machine dependent, meaning it could be 8 bytes and could be anything else. For network use, consider using a fixed length integer type in network byte order (if you don't need it now, you might need it in the future).

Comment: @MattDavis I added the function above

Comment: @Myst yeah I'm aware that my code isn't very portable because of that.  That's because this is for a project that will be run only on a specific VM and never in practice.  It's kinda dumb.

Comment: The line `filesize_string = (char*)&file_size;`is so not the right way to get an 8-byte representation of the file size.

Comment: @SteveSummit the function should work for any char * passed into it, i.e. an 8-Byte char * passed into it.  and it should also work to send the file contents when I call write_to_server() with the actual file contents later.  I left that part out though.

Comment: @SteveSummit how would you suggest getting the 8-Byte representation of the file size?

Comment: Well then you need to tell it to send 8 bytes, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `strlen()` to determine the length of binary data.   It'll miscount the data as soon as it sees a zero (NUL) byte in the binary encoding of the length field.

Write a more "primitive" function that takes the address of the data *and* its length as parameters, e.g.

```
void write_to_server_raw(const void *message, size_t message_size) {
    ...
}
```

If you still need the ability to send NUL terminated strings you can then rewrite your existing `write_to_server()` function so that it calls the new function to do the real work.

```
void write_to_server_string(const char *message) {
    size_t message_size = strlen(message);
    write_to_server_raw(message, message_size);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow I'm stupid!  Thank you so much, definitely going to try this.

Comment: Hmmm,  I'd expect  `size_t message_size = strlen(message) + 1;`

Comment: @chux that depends on whether the binary encoding has to include the NUL byte or not.    The OP's original code didn't.  I suspect that in reality the OP doesn't actually want to use a `_string` method anyway, because they're building a protocol to transfer arbitrary files that might contain raw binary data.